# GCM phonegap plugin Error on message

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I am using phonegap to implement GCM on android. The process works well until I send a message to the device. When my device receives the message it shuts down with the message that my app had an internal error... The error message is from the dalvik VM. I am still testing using the demo app that came in with the plug in.

The error in LogCat is:

Activity com.cordova2.gcm.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver@4a31f700 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

Comment: Can you paste the Error message on Logcat ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call this in your mainactivity to get rid of that error

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: I have similar problems, i tried it but it doesn't work, any other solution. Am using cordova 2.2.0